# Align a rotated fixed-position HTML block with right hand side of window using CSS3's transform: rotate(-90deg)

Tags: css

Is it possible to rotate a fixed-position block of text 90 degrees and then align it flush to the right-hand side of a window?

I've some code that [demonstrates the problem on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvhbU/). The code is:

**HTML:**

```
<html><body>
<div>This is not flush with the right.</div>
<p>This is flush<br/> with the right</p>
</body></html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;  
}

div {
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    right: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: pink;
}

p {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 100px
}
```

In Google Chrome 14.0.835.163 the `<div>` is not aligned to the right hand side. I suspect it's because the transform/rotation is performed after an alignment (which is the expected behaviour). However, is there a way using HTML/CSS to have a transformed/rotated block of text aligned to the right-hand side of a window?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform-origin):

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
```

See [your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvhbU/1/).

Comment: This just saved me punching a hole through the wall.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate id dynamically:

```
$(".boktlacidlo").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).prev()
    $(this).width(text.height())
    var padding = Number(text.css('padding-top').replace('px',''))
    var w = Number($(this).width()) +2*padding
    var h = Number($(this).height()) +2*padding
    var s = w+h 
    $(this).css({'transform-origin':h/s/100+'% '+w/s/100+'%', 
                 'msTransformOrigin':Math.round(h/s/100)+'%           '+Math.round(w/s/100)+'%',
                 'margin-top':w, 
                 'margin-right':-w+h-1});
```

I don't know, why I calculated ratio, but it works. Class .boktlacidlo has property transform: rotate(-90deg);